# WebStorm - Object structure refactoring

Tags: typescript, refactoring, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, automated-refactoring

In WebStorm, I would really like to know if there's a way to refactor the structure of objects.

Let's say I have this object,

```js
inventory = {
  fruits: [
    {type: 'apple', quantity: 24},
    {type: 'orange', quantity: 12}
  ] 
}
```

which is being used in a for loop further down the file/class

```js
for (const fruit of this.inventory.fruits) { ... }
```

---

Now, if I want to change it to

```js
inventory = {
  edibles: {
    fruits: [
      {type: 'apple', quantity: 24},
      {type: 'orange', quantity: 12}
    ]
  } 
}
```

and

```js
for (const fruit of this.inventory.edibles.fruits) { ... }
```

---

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve with **WebStorm refactoring**? Or with any **JetBrains IDE** for that matter.

Thanks

Comment: there are no refactorings allowing this; if you miss them, please feel free to file a feature request to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clearing that up